# How can I use Release pipeline to deploy to openshift

Tags: azure-pipelines, openshift, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-devops-server, azure-pipelines-release-task

I am working with Azure Devops server, CI is handled by build pipeline, now I want to use Release pipeline to be able to deploy the built image of the code to openshift, How can I achieve this ?
I am using quay to store the images, and will use an image from quay repository to pull, and re-tag it in order to promote it to production env.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to install the extension [OpenShift Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=redhat.openshift-vsts), this Azure DevOps extension offers tasks for integrating OpenShift into your build and release pipelines, for example by executing user defined `oc` commands.

Refer to [Introduction to the Red Hat OpenShift deployment extension for Microsoft Azure DevOps](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2019/12/05/introduction-to-the-red-hat-openshift-deployment-extension-for-microsoft-azure-devops/) and [Getting started](https://github.com/redhat-developer/openshift-vsts/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md) for more details.

The following blog for your reference:

- [How to rock CI/CD with Azure DevOps and OpenShift in 6 easy steps](https://www.opensourcerers.org/2021/05/31/how-to-rock-ci-cd-with-azure-devops-and-openshift-in-6-easy-steps/)